# Add all versions to the OpenApi doc

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm very sorry for my poor knowledge here but I think I'm missing something. I want to generate OpenApi docs to my .Net Core Web app. I also want to use versions for my methods.

So I do it like this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/Do")]
public class DoController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet]
  [ApiVersion("1.0")]
  [ApiVersion("2.0")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get() 
  {}
}
```

And in my startup I configure it like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
  {
    opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    opt.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0);
    opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
    opt.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
      new QueryStringApiVersionReader("api-version"),
      new HeaderApiVersionReader("X-Version"),
      new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("ver"));
  });
  services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(opt =>
  {
    opt.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    opt.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
  });

  services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
  {
    opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "title v1", Version = "v1" });
    opt.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "title v2", Version = "v2" });
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
  {
    c.DocumentTitle = "title doc";
    foreach (var desc in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
      c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{desc.GroupName}/swagger.json", desc.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
  });
}
```

Now, if I want to add a version 3.0 to my API, do I really need to add one more of these

```
opt.SwaggerDoc("v3", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "title v3", Version = "v3" });
```

Or should I create a loop there as well and call SwaggerDoc on all ApiDescriptions?
It feels a little strange that I need to add all of these versions manually. OR maybe I am doing something totally wrong here.

And another thing, my doc will not replace the versions in the endpoint.
[image]

If I don't set the `ApiVersionReader = xxx` then the endpoint will have a nice looking version in it.

[image]